# Grails GORM sort by CASE statement

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to use a `CASE` statement to order by GORM query. What I have is a view with a column of `state` the value there can be a state abbreviation or the word `General`. I will run the query like this

```
Dropdown.findByStateInList(['General','CA'], [sort: "stateOrderBy", order: "asc"]
```

but it returns an error of

```
could not resolve property: stateOrderBy of: workspace.Dropdown
```

When I create my domain class like below the value of `stateOrderBy` is the string `CASE WHEN state = 'General' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END` and not a 1 or 2 which is why I'm getting the error above. Is there a way to evaluate my CASE statement?

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields=true)
class Dropdown implements Serializable {
  String state
  String dropDownNames
  String sectionName
  String prefix
  Integer displayOrder
  def stateOrderBy = "CASE WHEN state = 'General' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END"

  static transients = [ "stateOrderBy" ]

  static mapping = {
    datasource 'plDropdown'
    table 'view_AllTables'
    id composite: ['state','sectionName','displayOrder']
    state column:'state'
    dropDownNames column:'DropDownNames'
    sectionName column:'SectionName'
    prefix column:'Prefix'
    displayOrder column:'DisplayOrder'
    stateOrderBy column:'stateOrderBy'
    version false
  }
}
```

EDIT: There will always be a result in the `General` column, but there may not be a result for the state specific query. If there is a state specific answer returned I want to use that otherwise the General answer.

Comment: Is is necessary to use the findBy? I think you could try with executeQuery: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

Comment: I could use that, but this will be used in many places and writing a query each time would be unnecessary extra work.

Comment: Yeah. But you could define this in a static method in your domain and reuse it at all places.

Answer (score 0):

GORM/Hibernate sorting is done by domain/entity properties. GORM will not evaluate a property as a SQL statement. That's a good thing because it's dangerous.

What *might* work is creating a SqlProjection with a Criteria query:

```
Dropdown.withCriteria {
    'in'('state', ['General','CA'])

    projections {
        property('state')
        property('dropDownNames')
        property('sectionName')        
        property('prefix')
        property('displayOrder')

        sqlProjection "CASE WHEN state = 'General' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END as stateSortBy", 'stateSortBy', org.hibernate.type.IntegerType as org.hibernate.type.Type
    }

    order('stateSortBy', 'asc')
}
```

That will create a property on the fly that would be sorted by. Although I think it would be better to do the equivalent in the view. Then you'd be able to sort by that property, even with a Dynamic Finder.

In the sqlProjection example above, the `stateSortBy` property that's created on the fly would contain the value 2 or 1. That's probably not want you want, so you'll need to replace those with the table column names those ordinals refer to. Then, you'll need to change the [hibernate type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/Type.html) to one that's appropriate. Which means the two columns must either be of the same type or be casted as such. In SQL terms, what you want is a new calculated field with the value to sort by.

Note that because projections are being used, the result will be a List containing the projected properties (table columns). It will not be a List.

About Domain.executeQuery() and Domain.findAll(sql), those are for HQL rather than SQL.

Comment: This looks good. I think we can use it with named queries https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html